# Calling a SOAP service requiring certificate using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

Nodejs SOAP client throwing error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames:

I am trying to call a SOAP service using [soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap]) in nodejs. However I am getting error **[ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is not in the cert's list:**. I am new to nodejs and not sure how to call a SOAP service which requires certificate from nodejs. Other ways to call SOAP services requiring certificates in Nodejs are also welcome.

```
var url = "https://soapserviceurl?wsdl";

soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) { 
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error Occurred!!");
        console.log(err);       
    }
    else {
        console.log(client.describe());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

please try

```js
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0" //this is insecure
```

Or:

```js
    var soap = require('soap'),
        request = require('request'),
        fs = require('fs');

    var url = "https://soapserviceurl?wsdl";
    
    var req = request.defaults({
       strictSSL: false
    );

    soap.createClient(url, { 
            request : req
    }, function(err, client) {
     //your code
    });
```

Or:

```js
soap.createClient(url, { 
            request : req,
      wsdl_options: {
            cert: fs.readFileSync('cert/cert.pem'), //path to pem
            key: fs.readFileSync('cert/cert.key'),   //path to private key
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    }, function(err, client) {
     //your code
});
```

Comment: Thanks. First two approaches worked perfectly fine. I have copied the certificate from browser using site information (small lock symbol at the beginning of url). How can I get the private key?

Comment: You could try to generate it using a utility like OpenSSL.  But I suppose you will get another error,regarding to self-signed certificates which aren't trusted because they are  not generated by a CA ,trusted authority (which should provide it to your organization).

Comment: `TypeError: req.then is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

The answer above doesn't work anymore because as of SOAP as of v0.40.0, it uses Axios for web requests, and not the `request` package. I couldn't find a recent answer for this and I spent a while figuring it out.

See in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap):

> request (Object): Override the default request module (Axios as of v0.40.0).
>
> wsdl_options (Object): Set options for the request module on WSDL requests. If using the default request module, see [Request Config | Axios Docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config).

Based on the link above and instructions like these https://smallstep.com/hello-mtls/doc/client/axios, this is the new way to do it:

First, so the WSDL endpoint is fetched with authentication, get the client like this:

```js
import soap from 'soap';
import fs from 'fs';
import https from 'https';

const client = await soap.createClientAsync(api_url, {
    wsdl_options: {
        httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
            key: fs.readFileSync('personal.key'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync('personal.cert'),
        }),
    }
});
```

The key difference is that instead of passing `cert` and `key` in `wsdl_options`, you have to pass a `new https.Agent` with the `cert` and `key`.

Next, before making any call, ensure they are also called with certificate authentication:

```js
client.setSecurity(new soap.ClientSSLSecurity('personal.key', 'personal.cert'));
```