# How do I translate this PHP SoapClient code into node.js using node-soap?

Tags: node.js, soap, soap-client, translate, node-soap

I am completely new to SOAP Api's and have an API that only accepts SOAP requests. The documentation is very bad to non-existent, but they do have some example implementations showing everything of in PHP, Java and .Net. I am able to understand the PHP code slightly and My goal is and I have tried to translate it to JS with "soap", but I just get the error: `connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:80`. The API requires the use of certificates and needs TLS 1.2 handshaking.

**Here is the code snippit in PHP, that I want to translate into Node.js with node-soap:**

```
function createSoapClient()
{
    $sslOptions = array(
        'local_cert' => $_POST['certifikat'],
        'verify_peer' => true,
        'cafile' => $_POST['ca'],
        'CN_match' => 'kt-ext-portwise.statenspersonadressregister.se');

    $streamcontext = stream_context_create(
        array('ssl' => $sslOptions));

    $options = array(
        'location' => $_POST['url'],
        'stream_context' => $streamcontext);

    // For the client to be able to read the file locally it requires a "file:// in front of the path"
    $wsdl = 'file://' . dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'resurser/personsok-2021.1.wsdl';

    return new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
}
```

**I seem to be able to create a Soap Client but when I call the Soap function "PersonSok" it throws me that error: `connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:80`. I use express to start the node.js project. Here is my code so far: (the two functions and only a part of the whole code)**

```
// Send request
export function sendRequest() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var args = { "Identifieringsinformation": createIdentifieringsInformation()};
        args["PersonsokningFraga"] = {"IdNummer": 195704133106};

        console.log("Passing arguments to PersonSok: " + args);
        
        // Create soap client
        createSoapClient().then((client) => {
            client.PersonSok(args, function (err, result) {
                if(err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

// Create SOAP Client
export function createSoapClient() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        var url = './assets/personsok.wsdl';

        // The commented code below is just some methods I have tried, but still same error.
        /*
        const secureContext = tls.createSecureContext({
            cert: fs.readFileSync('assets/Kommun_A.pem'),
            ca: fs.readFileSync('assets/DigiCert.pem'),
        });
        */

        //var client = await soap.createClientAsync(url, { secureContext, secureOptions: tls.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2, rejectUnauthorized: false });

        var client = await soap.createClientAsync(url, { rejectUnauthorized: false, strictSSl: false, secureOptions: tls.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2 });
        var wssec = new soap.ClientSSLSecurity('assets/private-key.pem', 'assets/csr.pem', 'assets/public-cert.pem');
        client.setSecurity(wssec);

        if(!client) {
            reject("Error: could not create SOAP client.");
        }

        console.log("Created SOAP Client");
        resolve(client);
    });
}
```

I appreciate all the help I can get! :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I finally found a working translation.** In this case I am trying to post a request to the Swedish SPAR API (Statens personadressregister) so there could be differences between this and the API your are trying to reach.

But on the road I got confronted with three errors after each other, **here is how I fixed them:**

Error 1: *"ECONNECTREFUSED ::1:80"*
Solution to error 1: In my previous test code I didn't set an endpoint to where the request should go as there is in the PHP option "location" corresponding to `client.setEndpoint(url)`. I can't really explain this, but [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75053871/16420701) set the cert and key option in both the `client.ClientSSLSecurity()` and in a new and overriden `HttpAgent` inside of the `wsdl_options` of the created SOAP client.

Error 2: *"ECONNECT socket hangup"*
Solution to error 2: I saw, that my previous SOAP request had a default header of "connection": "close". I suppose, that the connection for some reason close before any response could be finished. The solution was therefore to add the code: `client.addHttpHeader("connection", "keep-alive")`. I also saw this solution for others on stack overflow having a similar error.

In this stage I was able to establish a connection and a successful auth between my client and SPAR's API.

Error 3: Validation error
Solution to error 3: So this is more of a specific error relating to the API I was trying to reach, but might also become a problem of your's. I realised, that my arguments has to be in a correct order of the object, otherwise it will throw (in my case) a validation error. Check your wsdl for more information on this!
For example this didn't work for me:

```
const args = {
   arg2: blabla,
   arg1: blabaa,
   ...
}
```

Last but not least, here is the entire code. Fill in the information, that you need to make your request. This one worked ME and I am just around 40 intensive hours experienced with SOAP so far, so don't take my word for everything. I just tried explain with the best of my knowledge :)

```js
const soap = require('soap');
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

const wsdlUrl = "url";
const endpoint = "url";
const cert = "pathToCert";
const key = "pathToKey";

const args = { 
    {yourArgs}
};

// Create Client
async function createClient() {
    var sec = new soap.ClientSSLSecurity(
        key, // key
        cert, // cert
    );

    var client = await soap.createClientAsync(wsdlUrl, { 
        wsdl_options: {
            httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
                key: fs.readFileSync(key),
                cert: fs.readFileSync(cert),
            }),
        },
    });
    client.addHttpHeader('connection', 'keep-alive');
    client.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    client.setSecurity(sec);
    

    return client;
}

// Send soap request with custom arguments
async function sendSOAPRequest(args) {
    var client = await createClient();
    var result = await client.MyFunction(args);

    return result;
}




app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Node-SOAP test.");
});
app.get('/yourNodeJSEndpoint', async (req, res) => {
    var result = await sendSOAPRequest(args);
    res.send(result);
});
  
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Ask me if you have any questions, suggestions or better explanations on this matter.